# sql query to get static result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis-2012

i have a data  of numbers:
123456789

i needed it to be converted into :
123-45-6789

and if my data is like : 56789  and 456789
it should be converted to : 5-6789  and -45-6789

where i need an sql query to get this coneverted auomatically(column) based on data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another option

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (123456789)
,(56789)
,(456789)
,(6789)

Select *
      ,ltrim(replace(stuff(stuff(str(SomeCol,9),6,0,'-'),4,0,'-'),' -',''))
 From  @YourTable
```

Returns

```
SomeCol     (No column name)
123456789   123-45-6789
56789       5-6789
456789      45-6789
6789        6789
```

Comment: if data :6789 i need the result: just 6789 but your query results: -6789 and

Comment: yeah i have checked that but i dont need '-' for 456789  result: -45-6789 required result: 45-6789 if my data is 123456789 i required: 123-45-6789

Answer (score 0):

You should not use sql to format your result, exception is date and time. You should format the result in code

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to count from the end of the string.  I would suggest something like this:

```
select (case when len(str) <= 4 then str
             when len(str) = 5 then left(str, 1) + '-' + right(str, 4)
             when len(str) > 5 then stuff(str, 1, len(str) - 6, '') + '-' + left(right(str, 6), 2) + '-' + right(str, 4)
        end)
```

Comment: The stuff function requires 4 argument(s).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?:

```
select FORMAT(@yourNumber, N'###-##-####')
```

You can find out more about FORMAT method here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql